# underscore - locating node based in a value

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

This is my 1st time using underscore...I've this simple json...

```
"categories" : [ 
    {
        "tag" : "cat1",
        "active" : true,
        "order" : 10,
        "title" : {
            "en" : "Category 1",
            "pt" : "Categoria 1"
        },
        "children" : [ 
            {
                "tag" : "cat11",
                "active" : true,
                "order" : 10,
                "title" : {
                    "en" : "Category 1.1",
                    "pt" : "Categoria 1.1"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "tag" : "cat12",
                "active" : true,
                "order" : 20,
                "title" : {
                    "en" : "Category 1.2",
                    "pt" : "Categoria 1.2"
                }
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "tag" : "cat2",
        "active" : true,
        "order" : 10,
        "title" : {
            "en" : "Category 2",
            "pt" : "Categoria 2"
        },
        "children" : [ 
            {
                "tag" : "cat21",
                "active" : true,
                "order" : 10,
                "title" : {
                    "en" : "Category 2.1",
                    "pt" : "Categoria 2.1"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "tag" : "cat22",
                "active" : true,
                "order" : 20,
                "title" : {
                    "en" : "Category 2.2",
                    "pt" : "Categoria 2.2"
                }
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "tag" : "cat3",
        "active" : true,
        "order" : 10,
        "title" : {
            "en" : "Category 3",
            "pt" : "Categoria 3"
        },
        "children" : [ 
            {
                "tag" : "cat31",
                "active" : true,
                "order" : 10,
                "title" : {
                    "en" : "Category 3.1",
                    "pt" : "Categoria 3.1"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "tag" : "cat32",
                "active" : true,
                "order" : 20,
                "title" : {
                    "en" : "Category 3.2",
                    "pt" : "Categoria 3.2"
                }
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "tag" : "cat4",
        "active" : true,
        "order" : 10,
        "title" : {
            "en" : "Category 4",
            "pt" : "Categoria 4"
        },
        "children" : [ 
            {
                "tag" : "cat41",
                "active" : true,
                "order" : 10,
                "title" : {
                    "en" : "Category 4.1",
                    "pt" : "Categoria 4.1"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "tag" : "cat42",
                "active" : true,
                "order" : 20,
                "title" : {
                    "en" : "Category 4.2",
                    "pt" : "Categoria 4.2"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

you can see I've the TAG key in several places. I need to get the entire tree based in a criteria for tag. I was using, find, filter, where and findWhere and all the time I got the same results:

```
 var find = _.find($rootScope.webshop.categories, {tag: 'cat1'});
```

this works !

but if I try...

```
 var find = _.find($rootScope.webshop.categories, {tag: 'cat11'});
```

No results :( Even using _.where or ._filter or ._findWhere. - The results always will be the same.
Can someone help a beginner in Underscore with something that's probably simple ?!

ty !

Answer (score 1):

`_.find` does not recurse, you will have to build your own solution. Something like this:

```
_.findIn = function() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  var childrenProp = args[0];
  var result = _.find.apply(_, args.slice(1));
  if (result !== void(8)) return result;
  var arr = args[1];
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    args[1] = arr[i][childrenProp];
    var result = _.findIn.apply(_, args);
    if (result !== void(8)) return result;
  }
  return void(8);
}

_.findIn('children', categories, {tag: 'cat11'})
```

```js
categories = [ 
    {
        "tag" : "cat1",
        "active" : true,
        "order" : 10,
        "title" : {
            "en" : "Category 1",
            "pt" : "Categoria 1"
        },
        "children" : [ 
            {
                "tag" : "cat11",
                "active" : true,
                "order" : 10,
                "title" : {
                    "en" : "Category 1.1",
                    "pt" : "Categoria 1.1"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "tag" : "cat12",
                "active" : true,
                "order" : 20,
                "title" : {
                    "en" : "Category 1.2",
                    "pt" : "Categoria 1.2"
                }
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "tag" : "cat2",
        "active" : true,
        "order" : 10,
        "title" : {
            "en" : "Category 2",
            "pt" : "Categoria 2"
        },
        "children" : [ 
            {
                "tag" : "cat21",
                "active" : true,
                "order" : 10,
                "title" : {
                    "en" : "Category 2.1",
                    "pt" : "Categoria 2.1"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "tag" : "cat22",
                "active" : true,
                "order" : 20,
                "title" : {
                    "en" : "Category 2.2",
                    "pt" : "Categoria 2.2"
                }
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "tag" : "cat3",
        "active" : true,
        "order" : 10,
        "title" : {
            "en" : "Category 3",
            "pt" : "Categoria 3"
        },
        "children" : [ 
            {
                "tag" : "cat31",
                "active" : true,
                "order" : 10,
                "title" : {
                    "en" : "Category 3.1",
                    "pt" : "Categoria 3.1"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "tag" : "cat32",
                "active" : true,
                "order" : 20,
                "title" : {
                    "en" : "Category 3.2",
                    "pt" : "Categoria 3.2"
                }
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "tag" : "cat4",
        "active" : true,
        "order" : 10,
        "title" : {
            "en" : "Category 4",
            "pt" : "Categoria 4"
        },
        "children" : [ 
            {
                "tag" : "cat41",
                "active" : true,
                "order" : 10,
                "title" : {
                    "en" : "Category 4.1",
                    "pt" : "Categoria 4.1"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "tag" : "cat42",
                "active" : true,
                "order" : 20,
                "title" : {
                    "en" : "Category 4.2",
                    "pt" : "Categoria 4.2"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]


_.findIn = function() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  var childrenProp = args[0];
  var result = _.find.apply(_, args.slice(1));
  if (result !== void(8)) return result;
  var arr = args[1];
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    args[1] = arr[i][childrenProp];
    var result = _.findIn.apply(_, args);
    if (result !== void(8)) return result;
  }
  return void(8);
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(_.findIn('children', categories, {tag: 'cat11'})));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: OMG, dude ! I was expecting something like a missing parameter, maximum a sort of additional lib...could't wonder that's necessary a custom solution. And you was very generous providing me the soltion. tyvm !

Comment: Hey...sorry to bother you again..your code works good on children of the 1st category (cat11 ok, cat12 ok), but to any other children..this does not works :( Any clue ?